# Best way to control branch access in Git

Tags: git

I have a repo, lets call it apiProject.  It has a bunch of branches (master, development, feature branches, etc.), including a branch called companyB.

I'd like to share the companyB branch with a company (call it BCorp) that I'm collaborating with, but I'd like to keep the rest of the code private.  I'd also like to be able to continue supporting companyB by merging updates into it.  Because I want to support it, I don't want to just send BCorp a zipped folder of the companyB code.  Is there a good way to use Git to do this?

I was thinking I could fork the repo into apiProjectFork, and then delete the private branches from apiProjectFork before sharing it with BCorp.  Then I could continue to develop on apiProject, and I would still be able to use Git to update apiProjectFork.  Would that work?  I haven't worked with forks very much, so I'm not sure if they're appropriate for this use case.

Comment: I think you should do a bare clone of your repository, delete all branches but one, configure the remote origin to only fetch that branch and publish that repository. Then just do a periodic `git fetch` on that. Maybe even use a hook in the master repository to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to hide branches on git level, maybe on hosting level. maybe gitlab contains some feature, github contains protected branches (protect push): https://github.com/blog/2137-protected-branches-improvements

as far as i know, bitbucket has no solutions for this

Answer (score 0):

If "keep the rest of the code private" means that they should receive only changes from their dedicated branch you have two options:

1. keep your git repo private and push the changes from the branch to their server: `git push companyB_git companyB`. Thus, they will receive only changes from that branch. But in this case there're chances that one day you push something inappropriate, e.g. when you merge private branches into the CompanyB's branch, you disclose the complete history of entire private branch etc.
2. Organize a completely separated repository for CompanyB and export appropriate changes periodically. Essentially it's an equivalent of git archive, more or less. Thus, you get better security and control but lesser convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but I ended up running out of time and had to send a code packet with no version control.  I hope in the future to implement one of these solutions, and if I do I'll update this question accordingly.